# Grab section of text where a string resides

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
# Query 1:
.
.
.
# Hosts ip-127-0-0-1
.
.
.

# Query 2:
.
.
```

In my file there might be multiple queries; I only want to extract the information when my ip is NOT a certain value.

For example here I want to capture starting with '# Query 1' up until the space right before where it says '# Query 2' -- however I need to do this ONLY if Hosts ip does NOT match ip-127-0-0-1. This isn't an exact match as ip-127-0-0-1 can have other text appended to the end like ip-127-0-0-1.notusefultext

I'm open to using awk, sed or python to assist with this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, parse your query, and if you find the localhost ip, ignore it. Use something like `String.find()` that will look for the substring in your string.

Comment: I've updated my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^# Query [0-9]*:/{:a;N;/^\s*$/M!ba;/Hosts.*127-0-0-1/I!p}' file
```

Use sed's `-n` option to only print explicitly. Focus on any line that begins `# Query n*:` where `n*` means zero or more digits (use `[^:]*` if this match is too specific). Gather up the current and following lines until (and including) an empty line. Test the collection of lines for the string `127-0-0-1` and if not present, print the collection. All other lines will not be printed.

N.B. The collection includes both the query line and the empty line, this may not be the case if the last query does not have an empty line as the last line of the file. This can be catered for by an ameliorated version:

```
sed -n '/^# Query [0-9]*:/{:a;$!{N;/^\s*$/M!ba};/Hosts.*127-0-0-1/I!p}' file
```

Comment: That works like intended. I came up with my own answer but gave you credit since you were first.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query file would be like below. Please try this Perl solution

```
$ cat query_ip.txt
# Query 1:
select a b c from
tab
# Hosts ip-127-8-8-1
where a = '1'

# Query 2:
select a b c from
tab2
# Hosts ip-127-0-0-1
where a = '1'

# Query 3:
select a b c from
tab3
# Hosts ip-127-9-9-1
where a = '1'

$  perl -0777 -ne ' $_.="# Query "; while( /(# Query.+?)(# Query.+)/smg ) { $x=$1 ; $_="$2"; print $x if not $x=~/ip-127-0-0-1/ } ' query_ip.txt
# Query 1:
select a b c from
tab
# Hosts ip-127-8-8-1
where a = '1'

# Query 3:
select a b c from
tab3
# Hosts ip-127-9-9-1
where a = '1'

$
```

or try this.

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(# Query.+?)(# Query.+|\Z)/smg ) { $x=$1 ; $_="$2"; print "$x\n" if not $x=~/ip-127-0-0-1/ } ' query_ip.txt
# Query 1:
select a b c from
tab
# Hosts ip-127-8-8-1
where a = '1'


# Query 3:
select a b c from
tab3
# Hosts ip-127-9-9-1
where a = '1'
$
```

Comment: This does not. It prints all queries regardless of IP.

Comment: Are you able to replicate with my test file?.  Please share your actual input

Answer (score 0):

Given those `anchors` are exact, and there's nothing before `# Query 1:`,
try this please:

```
awk -v RS="# Query 2" 'FNR<2 && !/# Hosts ip-127-0-0-1/'
```

Judge from your own trying, if you want only lines starts with a letter in the block you described:

```
awk -v RS="# Query 2" -F"\n" 'FNR<2 && !/# Hosts ip-127-0-0-1/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~ "^[A-Za-z]") print $i}'
```

If the conditions are somewhat different, please leave comment.

Comment: This just prints out everything from Query 1 up until the next time it says "# Query"

Comment: @user3299633  Yes, what do you want? Add some solid example input and your expected output in your question.

Comment: @user3299633  Try the updated one, see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Final working solution:

```
# Pull in isolated code block for each individual query and write to unique file.
TEMP='temp_file'
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^#[[:space:]]Query[[:space:]][0-9].* ]]; then
        new_query='1'
        ((counter++))
        echo "$line" > ${TEMP}_${counter}
    else
        new_query='0'
        echo "$line" >> ${TEMP}_${counter}
    fi
done < "${LONG_RUNNING_QUERIES}"

# Remove first file, as it only contains query statistics for all long running queries.
rm ${TEMP}_0

# For all files that don't contain the IP, group them together in one file.
QUERIES_TO_GRAB='master_file'
> $QUERIES_TO_GRAB
for i in $(ls -v1 temp_file_*); do
    match=$(grep "${IP_ADDY}" "$i")
    if [ -z "$match" ]; then
        cat $i >> $QUERIES_TO_GRAB
    fi
done
```